# Extra data when convert PKCS7 to PEM certificate

Tags: openssl, converters, pem, pkcs#7

I converted a PEM certificate in PEM format to PKCS7 format, now I
am following [here](https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-converter.html) to convert back a PKCS7 (P7B) certificate file to PEM format. The result PEM file have content similar with the original PEM file, but its has an extra part of text as the begin.
The command is:

```
openssl pkcs7 -print_certs -in certificate.p7b -out certificate.cer
```

The output file (certificate.cer) contain an extra part of data **before** the "**-----BEGIN CERTIFICATION-----**", like below:
The first two lines: subject and issuer are the extra lines.

> subject=/C=VN/ST=HN/L=H/O=MyCompany/OU=MyCompany/CN=192.168.5.113
>
> issuer=/C=VN/ST=HN/O=MyCompany/OU=MyCompany Certificate
>   Authority/CN=MyCompany Intermediate CA
>
> -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
>
> MIIFwzCCA6ugAwIBAgICEBQwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQELBQAwgYMxCzAJBgNVBAYTAlZO
>   
>   MIGHMQswCQYDVQQGEwJWTjEMMAoGA1UECAwDVFRIMQowCAYDVQQHDAFIMRQwEgYD
>
> VQQKDAtWaWVncmlkIEpTQzEqMCgGA1UECwwhVmllZ3JpZCBKU0MgQ2VydGlmaWNh
>
> dGUgQXV0aG9yaXR5MRwwGgYDVQQDDBNWaWVncmlkIEpTQyBSb290IENBggIQAjAO
>
> BgNVHQ8BAf8EBAMCBaAwEwYDVR0lBAwwCgYIKwYBBQUHAwEwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEL
>
> BQADggIBAIrU8AyCq2OQzQaAzZeSJMrNCZg8/pukQcRhdOP+Gg9uIPFU+Sgjodt/
>
> vxczipxZii+qUOk7GGISvVRNFioSojVm8nawI0j5YvXss3+Zilwo7iqWP71NtO8u
>
> HGsk5GloCKO8cwbk9jQ1YrGXBi2829w1bJZBP1fuspgcdgDcDP0++IXdnYfyZ0eQ
>
> dQ/nwF4EaL2mP6kbZ24pqxem5DBwd3bvP3TMsyboVgKEnFGFZHIQ36y/wIjWp2xn
>
> CSWgi6byohaE6DmSMQ4yzCio38sgQ3fDM3VHnY81AijpFzCeBsIMhQJ9FF8SK+AL
>
> u2IaPU5+8XsPyIR6fsuwvuALa7a97gbP3mDoQKwUoIBOmh56cOoJDPj/+pbfg43i
>
> IJIXqk6/1ppxWhYS4/CtHBPas6bbcvQISif5WmEFV+kXmyXitmNCXOS9JSiinlBD
>
> 8lvggpzczqa8fOACIipdJ4zdh4a+lUKrAno+sdy+PDGUpmnG5VLdNNBRoYqovTe1
>
> fUcBZxRqVwO1ebZeBpJbQemw1CF/UzQgy1WixddSz/QNTbA821Ym/8OqoaUhy+PS
>
> idzOIV10iVXP6AOU8chPPnAZmXBgRbibHn8GrjrjXT0ll8YeysBlrmmre2CtY47V
>
> L9u++VhNjqBAht/gZnXS8GfGOkN9vNIFTu0MbWn4rrhJrr+tz09t
>
> -----END CERTIFICATE-----

I want to omit this part when converting, tried with parameters like -noout, -text but nothing works. How can I do it?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Answer (score 1):

After Googling, I found the solution here:
https://www.bo.infn.it/alice/introgrd/certmgr/node20.html

The "extra part" is "bag attributes". It can be removed by:

```
openssl x509 -in cert.pem -out certout.pem
```